# How to make React.Children.map work with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component named `WizardStep`:

```
const WizardStep: React.FC<{ title: string }> = () => { /*  */}
```

And another named `Wizard`. The latter accepts one or several `WizardStep` as children.

And it uses React.Children.map as follows:

```
Children.map(
   children, // a set of WizardStep
   ({ props: { title } }) => title
)
```

But Typescript says `TS2339: Property 'props' does not exist on type 'FC{ title: string; }>'.`

How do I go about this?

Comment: did you solve this? If so, how so?